# Editing XML with PowerShell and "file format" error

Tags: xml, encoding, powershell

I am using the HyperV Module from Codeplex to do a "config only" export from a 2008R2 Hyper-V server. In order to import the configuration on another HyperV server, I need to edit the value of CopyVMStorage in the EXP file. This file is an XML file. I wrote the following code in PowerShell to do the update for me. The variable $existing is the existing exp file.

```
$xml = [xml](get-content $existing)
$xpath = '//PROPERTY[@NAME ="CopyVmStorage"]'
foreach ($node in $xml.SelectNodes($xpath))
    {$node.Value = 'TRUE'}
$xml.Save($existing)
```

This code makes the correct changes to the XML. However, when I go to import the file on the Hyper-V server, I get an error that says "the file format is incorrect". I am wondering if the encoding of the file is incorrect or if there is something else going on. If I edit the file manually in wordpad, it imports without an issue.

I have noticed that the file that is updated with PowerShell comes out formatted whereas the raw file is xml all bunched together with no whitespace.

Any ideas on what "file format" could mean in this HyperV error message and how I might be able to use my code to automate this change in the XML and be able to use it to import the VM config?

XML Before

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
<DECLARATIONS>
  <DECLGROUP>
    <VALUE.OBJECT><INSTANCE CLASSNAME="Msvm_VirtualSystemExportSettingData"><PROPERTY NAME="Caption" TYPE="string"><VALUE>Virtual System Export Setting Data</VALUE></PROPERTY><PROPERTY NAME="CopySnapshotConfiguration" TYPE="uint8"><VALUE>0</VALUE></PROPERTY><PROPERTY NAME="CopyVmRuntimeInformation" TYPE="boolean"><VALUE>FALSE</VALUE></PROPERTY><PROPERTY NAME="CopyVmStorage" TYPE="boolean"><VALUE>FALSE</VALUE></PROPERTY><PROPERTY NAME="CreateVmExportSubdirectory" TYPE="boolean"><VALUE>TRUE</VALUE></PROPERTY><PROPERTY NAME="Description" TYPE="string"><VALUE>Microsoft Virtual System Export Setting Data</VALUE></PROPERTY><PROPERTY NAME="ElementName" TYPE="string"><VALUE>Microsoft Virtual System Export Setting Data</VALUE></PROPERTY><PROPERTY NAME="InstanceID" TYPE="string"><VALUE>Microsoft:A1F914F2-F38E-48A6-B1EE-58B84ECEAC0C</VALUE></PROPERTY><PROPERTY NAME="SnapshotVirtualSystem" TYPE="string"></PROPERTY></INSTANCE>
</VALUE.OBJECT>
```

XML After

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
<DECLARATIONS>
  <DECLGROUP>
    <VALUE.OBJECT>
      <INSTANCE CLASSNAME="Msvm_VirtualSystemExportSettingData">
        <PROPERTY NAME="Caption" TYPE="string">
          <VALUE>Virtual System Export Setting Data</VALUE>
        </PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="CopySnapshotConfiguration" TYPE="uint8">
          <VALUE>0</VALUE>
        </PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="CopyVmRuntimeInformation" TYPE="boolean">
          <VALUE>FALSE</VALUE>
        </PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="CopyVmStorage" TYPE="boolean">
          <VALUE>TRUE</VALUE>
        </PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="CreateVmExportSubdirectory" TYPE="boolean">
          <VALUE>TRUE</VALUE>
        </PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="Description" TYPE="string">
          <VALUE>Microsoft Virtual System Export Setting Data</VALUE>
        </PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="ElementName" TYPE="string">
          <VALUE>Microsoft Virtual System Export Setting Data</VALUE>
        </PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="InstanceID" TYPE="string">
          <VALUE>Microsoft:A1F914F2-F38E-48A6-B1EE-58B84ECEAC0C</VALUE>
        </PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="SnapshotVirtualSystem" TYPE="string">
        </PROPERTY>
      </INSTANCE>
    </VALUE.OBJECT>
```

NOTE: This is a cross post from https://serverfault.com/questions/231186/code-to-update-hyperv-export-file. I believe this is actually more of a coding/dev problem rather than an IT Pro question.

Comment: Well, I suppose it's possible that the file _looks_ like XML but actually isn't (i.e. HyperV is bothered by formatting that shouldn't make a difference.) Can we see the XML, before and after? And can you look at the files in a binary editor, make sure PowerShell isn't add a Unicode BOM, or anything else that might be confusing something?

Comment: Are those the whole XML files? Because neither of those is well-formed XML; they're missing the closing tags for the `DECLGROUP` and `DECLARATIONS` elements...

Comment: They are not the whole file. It's the start of the file down to the end of the <instance/> tag I am changing. The files are actually fairly large. I wanted to minimize the amount of text I copied up there.

Comment: i looked in a binary editor and there doesn't seem to be anything funky at the beginning or end of the file on either the before or after

Comment: In a binary editor (or using Format-Hex from PSCX) you should see that the first two bytes are: `FF FE`.  You can make it that way by using an editor like Notepad2 which lets you choose the file encoding to use.

Comment: Well, assuming the rest of the file is okay, and that PowerShell is correctly writing the output as UTF-16, I can't see anything XML-y wrong at all. Might be worth running the "after" file through xmllint, if you have it hanging around, just to make sure the rest of the file is indeed well-formed, but other than that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Keith, both files do indeed start with FF FE

Comment: I would diff the file before and after you save it from PowerShell.  Perhaps you should be preserving whitespace (`$xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true`) or something like that in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating an XmlTextWriter and setting the Formatting property to "None" should accomplish what you are looking for.  You could try something like this and modify to your specific needs.

```
function NoFormat-XML ([xml]$xml)
{
    $StringWriter = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter
    $XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter $StringWriter
    $xmlWriter.Formatting = "None"
    $xml.WriteContentTo($XmlWriter)
    $XmlWriter.Flush()
    $StringWriter.Flush()
    Write-Output $StringWriter.ToString()
}
```