# Is there a way to read in a file, replace using a regex and output the file, without messing up the line endings and invalid characters?

Tags: regex, powershell, file-io

I have a ASCII file generated by Visual Studio that has inconsistent line endings and there is some character values that are > 127 in it.

I'd like to read in the file, perform a regex replace on the text (ignoring character values > 127) and then write the file back without changing the line endings or the characters of a value > 127.

The best that I have is:

```
(Get-Content $rcFile) -replace 
     "(FILEVERSION\s+|VALUE\s+`"(?:FileVersion|ProductVersion)`",\s+(`"))$old_major([,.])$old_minor2(?:\3)$old_minor1(?:\3)0",
     "`${1}$new_major`${3}$new_minor2`${3}$new_minor1`${3}0" | Set-Content "$rcfile.new"
```

But the line endings are not as they were.  There's a stray `\r` near the beginning and near the end that get converted to a `\r\n` with this.  I'd like to keep this as it was as it keeps being kicked back in by the VS environment and it causes the file to be checked out for no reason.

Is this a lost cause?

Comment: Try [no Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019403/editing-xml-with-powershell-and-file-format-error)

Comment: @lloyd, that link is for an XML file. The file that this is happening on is a plain text file.

Comment: Then a [casting issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041857/powershell-keep-text-formatting-when-reading-in-a-file). Perhaps include more than a partial line of powershell so I can tell what is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with PowerShell v3 [`Get-Content`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx) has a parameter `-Raw` to read an entire file without splitting it into an array of lines. However, `Set-Content` will always put CR-LF at the end of a string it writes, so that approach won't work for you.

Use the [`ReadAllText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`WriteAllText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods instead:

```
$txt = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($rcFile) -replace ...
[IO.File]::WriteAllText("$rcFile.new", $txt)
```

If needed you can specify the [encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the file read and/or the file to be written:

```
$txt = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($rcFile, $readEncoding) -replace ...
[IO.File]::WriteAllText("$rcFile.new", $txt, $writeEncoding)
```

Some encodings are available as pre-defined constants (e.g. `[Text.Encoding]::ASCII` or `[Text.Encoding]::UTF8`), but you can also define encodings by codepage. In this case the file was apparently encoded using the US OEM codepage (`[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('IBM437')`).

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that already.  That's why I stated `character values that are > 127` as this will mess up those characters.

Comment: Without seeing the actual content of the file the only other things I could suggest are to play with the encoding, or to edit the bytes of the file (`ReadAllBytes()`/`WriteAllBytes()`).

Comment: The file is an `.rc` file and the contents is mostly regular text with mostly `\r\n` line endings.  There are some `\r` line endings, and some strings that consist of characters of hex values `92`, `96`, `A3`, `A9`, and others.  I'll try and play around with the `encoding` parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure how to generate a new `[System.Text]::ASCIIEncoding` object in powershell.  Do you have an example?

Comment: `[Text.Encoding]::ASCII` or `[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($codepage)`. [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, already got that, but it says that it's unable to find type.  Can you post and example?  I've tried `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Text` but it complains that `Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'System.Text' could not be found.`

Comment: Ahh, nm.  Got it using `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Text.Encoding`.  ASCII didn't work, I'll try some others.

Comment: That was it.  I used `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('IBM437')` as my encoding type and it worked like a charm.  Update your answer to include switching encoding types with example(s) and I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Adjusted answer. Note that the `System.Text.Encoding` namespace is available by default in PowerShell. No `Add-Type` required.

Comment: Ahh. Yeah, Must have been using the wrong type path.  Thanks. :)